# Why IE does not store cookies when start it through watir

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, watir

When I start an IE with code: `browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie`
I get an instance of IE but it does not accept all cookies from a server.
It accepts 3 cookies out of 6. This causes my tests to fail because I am not able to access some services. Is there any way to force browser to accept all cookies form a specific server? I don't have this issue with firefox or chrome though.
IE is set up to accept any cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have the watir gem specified instead of watir-webdriver. For now, switch to watir-webdriver and it will use the same code as Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: Here what I am using:
`require 'watir-webdriver'`
`browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie`
So I am using webdriver.

Comment: Oh, right. You need to be using the 32 bit version of IEDriver and not the 64 bit one (regardless of what your OS supports).

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I am using 32 bit IEDriverServer v2.42.0.0

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't store couple of cookies you need for some service i think its something with the security of the browser what i'm doing in this cases i use other browsers that gives you all the cookies you need like (phantomJS, Firefox) [selenium]